# Windows Service stops after creating first folder

Tags: c#

I made a simple windows service that backups my "my docs" folder. In debug mode, it's working properly but after installation it does not work and the service automatically stops after creating the first folder.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(backupDirectory))
{
    DirectoryInfo DI = Directory.CreateDirectory(backupDirectory);

    foreach (string dirInMyDocs in Directory.GetDirectories(WorkStationMyDocuments, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirInMyDocs.Replace(WorkStationMyDocuments, backupDirectory));
    }
```

I have complete access to the folder and files, the program only runs on the first creation of folder and does not even run at `foreach` loop.

I also have a proper `OnStart` event with thread.

Comment: most frequent case for such behavior is unhandled exception. enclose you code inside try-catch block and add logging inside catch clause

Comment: inside the foreach loop it catch an exception "the path is not a legal form"

Comment: so your problem is "dir path creation" code. try to debug it and I hope you'll see the error

Comment: in debug it doesnt catch any exception, it works properly. but when i release it and create an installer, it doesnt work

Comment: aha! There is a difference between debug mode and release mode in your scenario. In debug mode your service is running under your account, but in release mode its probably under "Local system" account. If so, try to change your service scredentials via service controll manager, in properties. And check if the service is running correctly under your account in release mode

Comment: i dont know if this is correct but i change the account from LocalSystem to LocalService in serviceProcessInstaller1 and it still doesn't work

Comment: try to change account to yours, this could be a case. the problem could be in privileges. Or maybe you are trying to access some network resources from built-in account.

Comment: my account is admin, im just copying my documents folder to another location which i have access.

Comment: yes, you have access to that folder, but this may not be true for build-in account. all build-in accounts are not admin accounts(generally speaking they have more privilidges on several things but your folder is another case). And last that I can advice here - put logging after each step and you can fogure out what path cause the error